# NoneType from API?

Tags: python

Probably a very noobish problem but I just can't figure this out.

I'm calling a price info from server with .get command, then printing it out and then multiplying that price with the balance of my account.

Here is the code:

```
def ticker_sell(currency):

    ticker_sell = client.get_ticker(symbol=currency)
    ask_price = ticker_ask['askPrice']
    print (ask_price)

balance = 1

ltcusdt = ticker_sell('LTCUSDT')

sold_to_usdt = float(ltcusdt) * float(balance)
```

When running the code, it prints out the price as float, as it should. However, when this float should be multiplied by balance (=1) I am getting error code:

```
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'.
```

Is it possible that as I am calling value for key 'LTCUSDT', the key is somehow messing things up?

Comment: You need to add `return ask_price` to get a value back from the function, not `print`- None will always be returned otherwise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `ticker_sell` to this:

```
def ticker_sell(currency):

    ticker_sell = client.get_ticker(symbol=currency)
    ask_price = ticker_ask['askPrice']
    return ask_price
```

You need to have a return statement for `ticker_sell` to provide a value to `ltcusdt`